# Perform Excel "Text to Columns" action in CSV file using X++

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta

In Excel you can open a CSV file and click on "Text to Columns" (under "Data" tab) to have a column delimited file.

Is there any way to simulate this using X++? A class that would open the CSV file and apply the exact same Excel "Text to Columns" action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [InFieldDelimiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa849629%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) method of the [CommaIo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa894098%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) class to use the correct delimiters.

Or use [str2con](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa638592%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) to split a string.

You can even read an Excel file using [ExcelIo](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=ExcelIo).

**Update:**
As your file is not CSV use `str2con`:

```
for (con = commaIo.read(); commaIo.status() == IO_Status::Ok; con = commaIo.read())
{
    lineNum++;
    if (lineNum > 1 && conlen(con))
        con = str2con(conPeek(con,1));
    info(str2con(con));
}
```

This may not remove quotes and trailing spaces, do this for interesting string fields:

```
purchId = strRtrim(strRem(conPeek(con,3),'"'));
```

Comment: Thank you Jan, I was indeed testing with CommaIo and CommaTextIo.


The problem that occurs is when the CSV file has its first header row properly column delimited, then all the other rows gathering its entire data in 1 single column (with a comma delimiter).
So I used the CommaIo.inFieldDelimiter(",") to try and read single column rows but it kept sending the entire row in one single container.


I can manualy fix this in Excel using the "Text to Columns" action and properly read my file with CommaIo but can't seem to find a way to do this through X++.

Comment: Then split the first field using str2con. Could you upload your file?

Comment: A sample CSV file is available [here](http://goo.gl/9ti71) and the sample code I have [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Zk8tFfSIWU4s6de1XtcRgVBzn39HVqUVTL6H4-HRNwU/edit)

Comment: Let us hope that the strings does not contain commas! Then your best option is to ask the data provider correct their shitty output. That would be a good strategy!

Comment: Thanks Jan, strRtrim and strRem are handy. This somewhat CSV file was a sample downloaded from the online AMEX account statement and indeed has strings with commas like the amount values. I'm afraid I'll have to manage all of this through regular expressions...